# Bringing up a VM with vagrant, error installing librarian-chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox

So im trying to install a VM to dev and test ruby code. I am getting to the point of trying to install librarian-chef gem and im getting this error.

```
$ gem install librarian-chef
ERROR:  Error installing librarian-chef:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32/ext/win32-eventlog
D:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -rubygems D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32 RUBYLIBDIR=D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32
checking for windmc... yes
checking for windres... yes
 checking for gcc... yes
 windmc chef-log.man
windres -i chef-log.rc -o resource.o
gcc -o chef-log.dll -shared resource.o
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c

LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.3/ffi_c

LoadError: cannot load such file -- win32/eventlog

 Tasks: TOP => default => register
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

It then exits

Here is the contents of the gem_make.out file

```
current directory: D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32/ext/win32-eventlog
D:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -rubygems D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR=D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/chef-12.11.18-universal-   mingw32 RUBYLIBDIR=D:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/chef-12.11.18-universal-mingw32
checking for windmc... yes
checking for windres... yes
checking for gcc... yes
windmc chef-log.man
windres -i chef-log.rc -o resource.o
gcc -o chef-log.dll -shared resource.o
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c

LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.3/ffi_c

LoadError: cannot load such file -- win32/eventlog

 Tasks: TOP => default => register
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1
```

The guide im using is [This](http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2013/07/23/developing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows/) by the way. If anyone has a more appropriate guide that has helped them to configure and setup a vm for this use, i would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: I strongly recommend to not use librarian-chef, but berkshelf instead. I'd say that librarian is an outdated workflow that doesn't scale well.

Comment: Agreed, that guide is woefully out of date and shouldn't be used. The rails development workflow on Windows has improved dramatically over the past few years, you don't need Vagrant at all for development now.